# GET Query in SCIM API

Tags: slack, scim

We want to get data from Slack, using below parameters.
How to write the code to fire http request in c# or any other languauge?

https://api.slack.com/scim

```
 GET /scim/v1/Groups?startIndex=4&count=500 HTTP/1.1

 Host: api.slack.com

 Accept: application/json

 Authorization: Bearer xoxp-4956040672-4956040692-6476208902-xxxxxx
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use: https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk or if your better at Python https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient.

C#? I would just create asp.net mvc app and in your controllers(c) add services you would like to use within your main application. You wouldn't much need the view(v) here. Haven't used C# / ASP.NET MVC in a bit but yea.

The node-slack-sdk is pretty awesome. I would personally just that. They have examples for you to just paste in your editor. It works great w/in VSCode, and you can test initial commands within your Slack app with NGROK for redirect URLs.

Comment: Thanks @Jake_West, how to use node-slack-sdk in visual studio/ VS Code?

Comment: Install Node.js > Open VSCode > Create a file called 'app.js'  > add the code from here: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/ > open the terminal at the second to last top header sections called 'Terminal' > and run the command 'node app.js'. THis should create 'package.json' where you store module libraries within Node. From their that is a node.js skeleton. Next proceed to add follow: https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk by installing all the required node libraries via 'npm install [whatever_library_name]' command. Copy & Paste in Web API Usage code.